urllib3 with proxy returns UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED
I am trying to use urllib3 to connect a remote server. The remote server uses an obsolete SSL protocol, so I have to set up the custom SSL context with a flag "OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT":
        ctx = create_urllib3_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        ctx.options |= ssl.OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT
        ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION

        http = urllib3.PoolManager(
            ssl_context=ctx
        )

        response = http.urlopen(
            method='POST',
            url=servder_url,
            body=request_body,
            timeout=Timeout(connect=3.0, read=10.0),
            context=ctx
        )

This works just perfectly. But my code is going to be executed on a CI-CD machine, which has access to the remote server only through a proxy. So I do the following change:
        ctx = create_urllib3_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        ctx.options |= ssl.OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT
        ctx.options |= ssl.OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION

        proxy = urllib3.ProxyManager(
            proxy_url=http_proxy,
            proxy_ssl_context=ctx,
            use_forwarding_for_https=True
        )

        response = proxy.urlopen(
            method='POST',
            url=servder_url,
            body=request_body,
            timeout=Timeout(connect=3.0, read=10.0),
            context=ctx
        )

Now I get the following error:
Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/session
 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)')))

Do I understand correctly, that the custom SSL context (proxy_ssl_context) does not work correctly in ProxyManager?
I use Python 3.12.6 with urllib3 2.2.3
Thanks in advance!
